# Sumproducts #value! error

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to use the Sumproducts function, but get the #VALUE error

The code looks like this:
    =SUMPRODUCT('Combined Output Table'!AO4:BH4,'ECAP CONSTANTS'!B2:I2)

Both arrays are made up percentage values.

I use the second array in a Sumproducts function elsewhere where it works perfectly, and i have checked that the first array is only made up of number values (in percentage format).  Neither array has any characters or non-number values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two ranges need to be the same size, in your formula the first range is 20 cells, the second is only 8, so I don't know which cells should be multiplied but this should make it work

`=SUMPRODUCT('Combined Output Table'!AO4:BH4,'ECAP CONSTANTS'!B2:U2)`

Second range to finish at U2, making it the same size as the first range

Comment: Ah, thanks, need to rearrange the other array as the next column contains an unwanted value.

Comment: Text values in either range will be ignored, only error values should cause problems

Answer (score 1):

Your ranges aren't the same size. It makes no sense for the algorithm to try to multiply some value by some value that is not present, thus all the ranges in a SUMPRODUCT() must always match in size.